# How to display records of a database when a button is clicked using sqflite in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I have an alertbox in which I have 3 fields: tagname,modelname,type 
Now I have created a database and a table.
When I fill all the 3 fields and I click the submit button it should update the existing table with these new values

This is my class Device :

```
class Device{
  // final int id;
  int id;
  final String tagName;
  final String model;
  final String type;

  Device(this.tagName, this.model, this.type,{this.id});

  // Map from the object
   Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'tagName': tagName,
      'model': model,
      'type':type
    };
  }
}
```

This is the database and table ive created :

```
initDB() async {
    print("Initiating database");
    return await openDatabase(

        // Set the path to the database. Note: Using the `join` function from the
        // `path` package is best practice to ensure the path is correctly
        // constructed for each platform.
        join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'device_database.db'),
        onCreate: (db, version) {
      //this.id, this.tagName, this.model, this.type
      return db.execute(
         "CREATE TABLE device_allocation(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, deviceId INTEGER, empid INTEGER, updatedOn INTEGER, isActive INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '1');"
         "CREATE TABLE devices(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,tagName TEXT,model TEXT,type TEXT);"
         "CREATE TABLE user(empId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);"
          );
    },

     version: 1);
  }
```

This is where im performing Insert operation :

```
Future<void> insert(Device device) async {
    final db  = await database;
    await db.insert('devices', device.toMap(),conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);

  }
```

This is to generate the list :

```
Future<List<Device>> getDevices() async {
    final db = await database;
    final List<Map<String,dynamic>> maps = await db.query('devices');
    return List.generate(maps.length, (i){
      return  Device(
        maps[i]['tagName'],
        maps[i]['model'],
        maps[i]['type'],
        id:  maps[i]['id']
      );

    });
    }
}
```

When this button is clicked the new values should get updated to the existing table :

```
FlatButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
              child: Text('SUBMIT',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xffedac51),
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),

              onPressed: () {

                }
                     ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the generic answer :

There are two ways to read the data. One is Query method and other is RawQuery method. Sample code below :

Query Method :

```
Future<List> getCustomers() async {
  var result = await database.query("Customer", columns: ["id", "first_name", "last_name", "email"]);

  return result.toList();
}
```

RawQuery Method :

```
Future<List> getCustomers() async {
  var result = await database.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM Customer');
  return result.toList();
}
```

Coming back to your question, once you have the data in the List<> form, you can just set the state and accordingly update the screen.

Comment: Can u explain in detail? Or can u upload the entire code?

Comment: It's only one line of the code in both Query as well as RawQuery. Ask a specific question and I'll try to answer. For "Can you explain in detail ?", please refer [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite) or [this](https://www.techiediaries.com/flutter-sqlite-crud-tutorial/)

Comment: After pressing the flat button the list shld update

Comment: You'll need the code like below :
`List<Device> _listDevice = new List();
setState( () => _listDevice =  await getDevices() );` (It is assumed that getDevices() gets the list from the database). If you tied this list to the ListView then set state will update the data on the screen.